# Eliminar registros del tablas enlazadas

Tags: php, codeigniter

estoy con una duda, de repente alguno puede ayudarme... estoy siguiendo un tutorial en el que hacemos un sistema de ventas desde cero, el mismo como se imaginaran, es muy básico. pero muy útil, aprendí muchísimo con el. Una vez dicho esto quisiera plantearles mi consulta. en el tutorial no explica el procedimiento para eliminar registros de tablas enlazadas, por lo que cuando genero alguna venta estas no las puedo eliminar. forzando algunas veces elimine, pero después ya no podía guardar ninguna venta xq me da error en la llave foránea. Entonces me gustaría contar con las experiencia de los integrantes para conocer si hay alguna técnica especifica para este tipo de procedimiento o algún consejo q puedan darme!!

Desde ya muy agradecido!!
P.D. uso CodeIniter.

Comment: Saludos, a que te refieres con tablas enlazadas? tablas con relaciones  1 a 1, 1 a N, o,  N a N?

Comment: asi mismo Juan, especificamente mi tabla ventas esta relacionada con la tabla detalle de ventas, clientes, productos, etc.. gracias por el comentario amigo!!

Comment: necesitamos ver el schema de tu base de datos para ver como tienes relacionadas las tablas y todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres hacer eso una solucion es ponerle a tu tabla el ON DELETE CASCADE pero debes fijarte bien porque eso borra toda relacion

Supongamos que tienes las tablas CUARTOS y EDIFICIOS

```
CREATE TABLE EDIFICIOS(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    direccionVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE CUARTOS(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    edificios_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (edificio_id)
        REFERENCES EDIFICIOS(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Si tu tienes supongamos....
3 edificios, A,B,C
y tienes los cuartos asi: del 1 al 3 en el A, del 4 al 10 en el B, y del 11 al 15 en el C.

Cuando tu borres un edificio, todos sus cuartos se eliminaran. Normalmente te diria, no se puede eliminar el edificio porque esta relacionado con un cuarto y para eliminarlo tendrias que eliminar todos los cuartos primeros. Esto tiene su ventaja y desventaja.

Si te sirve el DELETE ON CASCADE adelante, pero en una relacion de Muchos a Muchos es decir
M x M

ahi son 3 tablas afectadas y la cosa se complica un poco. Te sugiero probar y ver si asi es como lo necesitas.

Comment: muchas gracias por la yuda amigo!!

Comment: Pero tiene su desventaja, no todo es color de rosa, si se adapta bien a lo que quieres que bueno, pero ten cuidado cuando lo uses asi, si mi respuestas te dio solucion marcalo como correcta para que me den puntos :3

Comment: Alexis si, estuve investigando, y creo q le encontre la mano a como usarla, pero no solucione mi problema porque no quiero q la venta desaparezca de mi bd, quiero solo que se resten los valores de la venta.. eso sigo investigando.. muchas gracias x la ayuda..

Comment: Eso es un poco complicado, si tienes 5 clientes y cada uno te compro 10 productos, y eliminas a 1 cliente es obvio que toda su informacion en las ventas se perdera PERO tu stock seguira igual. Lo que puedes hacer es una baja logica un campo en el cliente que sea "estado" para indicar si esta activo o inactivo. La otra cosa es que si de a fuerzas quieres eliminar al cliente, tendras que hacer una subconsulta y hacer que se le sume a tu stock todos los productos que el cliente compro.

Comment: @JoséAlexisCruzSolar ¿Y como controlas que un usuario CON CADA TABLA QUE TENGA UNA BAJA LOGICA (las cuales serian la mayoría) no te elimine y de de alta el mismo registro? Por ejemplo, dar de baja el registro de la tabla color con el nombre rojo, y que este te lo creé nuevamente. Podrías preguntar si existe el registro eliminado, pero con una letra que cambie, ya se tomaría como diferente, y también tendrías que controlar que no te lo cambie a "rojo" con una edición cuando este ya existe.